# Jquery custom filters in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want create a custom filters using jquery. 
I started here

```js
var filters = {};
var data = [];
var filters = {};
filters.id = 0;
filters.title = "Users";
data[0] = filters;
var filters = {};
filters.id = 1;
filters.title = "Title";
data[1] = filters;
var filters = {};
filters.id = 2;
filters.title = "Start date";
data[2] = filters;
var filters = {};
filters.id = 3;
filters.title = "End date";
data[3] = filters;
var filters = {};
filters.id = 4;
filters.title = "Price";
data[4] = filters;
var filters = {};
filters.id = 5;
filters.title = "Category";
data[5] = filters;

var i = 0;
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  if (i < 2) {
    $(".chooseFilter").append("<option data-filter-id=" + value.id + ">" + value.title + "</option>");
  } else {
    $(".chooseFilter").append("<option data-filter-id=" + value.id + " disabled>" + value.title + "</option>");
  }

  i++;
});

var dataHTMLFilters = [];
dataHTMLFilters[0] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="0" type="text" placeholder="Enter username">';
dataHTMLFilters[1] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="1" type="text" placeholder="Enter title">';
dataHTMLFilters[2] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="2" type="text" placeholder="Enter start date">';
dataHTMLFilters[3] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="3" type="text" placeholder="Enter end date">';
dataHTMLFilters[4] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="4" type="text" placeholder="Enter price">';
dataHTMLFilters[5] = '<input class="user" data-filterid="5" type="text" placeholder="Enter category">';



var limits = [];
limits[0] = 5;
limits[1] = 1;
limits[2] = 2;
limits[3] = 3;
limits[4] = 4;
limits[5] = 5;

$("body").on("change", ".chooseFilter", function() {
  var filterId = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-filter-id");
  $(this).parent().prev().html(dataHTMLFilters[filterId]);
});

var buttons = '<div><button class="add">add</button><button class="remove">remove</button></div>';
$("body").on("click", ".add", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var filterID = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").attr("data-filter-id");

  $(".filters").append("<div class='filter'><div>" + $(".chooseFilter")[0].outerHTML + '</div>' + buttons + "</div>");

  $(".filter").last().prepend("<div class='sibling'>" + dataHTMLFilters[$(".filter:last-child .chooseFilter option:not(:disabled)").attr("data-filter-id")] + "</div>");
  if ($(".chooseFilter option[data-filter-id=" + filterID + "]:selected").length >= limits[filterID]) {
    $(".chooseFilter option[data-filter-id=" + filterID + "]").prop("disabled", true);
    var filterIdSelected = $(".chooseFilter option:not(:disabled)").first().attr("data-filter-id");
    $(".chooseFilter").last().find("option[data-filter-id=" + filterIdSelected + "]").attr("selected", true);
    console.log(dataHTMLFilters[filterIdSelected]);
    $(".chooseFilter").last().parent().prev().html(dataHTMLFilters[filterIdSelected]);
  }

});

$("body").on("click", ".remove", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <div class="filter">
    <div class="sibling">
      <input class="user" data-filterid="0" type="text" placeholder="Enter username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <select class="chooseFilter" style="width: 100%;">

      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class="add ">add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Filters must fulfill,comatibile with:

1. Take limits to attention in add, remove and change. If limit is equal to instance of length in HTML document filter must be disabled
2. Basic filters are users, title when filters is only one this two option must be not disabled rest must be disabled when event is add, remove or change

Any ideas how I could do that? I try various method but result always are the same , filters is not compatibile.

If you want some more information how it should work just say.

I see it like this when add,remove and change:

```
if(users.length >= limit){
//set all option in select where filter is user to disabled = true
}

if(title.length >= limit){
//set all option in select where filter is title to disabled = true
}

if(filters.length > 1){
//options in select set to disable=false
}

if(filters.length < 1){
//options in select set to disable=true and title, users set to false
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What are the errors?

Comment: Aby idea how resolve this problem?